# Помогите со спиралью матрицы 1 условие не совпадает в моем коде. Python

Tags: python

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
matrix = [[0] * m for _ in range(n)]
num = 1

top_matrix = 0
bottom_matrix = n
left_matrix = 0
right_matrix = m

while num < n * m + 1:
        for i in range(left_matrix, right_matrix):
            matrix[top_matrix][i] = num
            num += 1
        top_matrix += 1
        for i in range(top_matrix, bottom_matrix):
            matrix[i][right_matrix -1] = num
            num += 1
        right_matrix -= 1
        for i in range(right_matrix -1, left_matrix -1, -1):
            matrix[bottom_matrix - 1][i] = num
            num += 1
        bottom_matrix -= 1
        for i in range(bottom_matrix -1, top_matrix -1, -1):
            matrix[i][left_matrix] = num
            num += 1
        left_matrix += 1

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(str(matrix[i][j]).ljust(3), end="")
    print()
```

Не могу понять как добавить условие при вводе значений равных (1) единицы матрица расползается, то есть:
ввод: 1 7 к примеру мне выдает:
13 12 11 10 9  8  7
или 9 1 результат:
1
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
как это исправить? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А что программа сделать должна?

Comment: заполнить матрицу по списали начиная от matrix[0][0]